# Routing fade modal in flask

Tags: python, flask

I am having an issue with my fading modal routing in flask. My user login opens a modal and i m trying to implement the POST feature from the modal in flask.

I thought of implementing under index and search for the form name form the the post like below.

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    if request.form.get('login', None)  == 'submit' :
        return 'Yeah hooo'
    return render_template('index.html')
```

However, when i execute the code above, i get

> Method Not Allowed

on /index. My other worries is that my Login form is in the template and can therefore be call from any routes. Since template is not a route. Please is there any way i can achieve this in flask ? Or do i have to take the login in to a seperate html file instead of the template ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should explicitly add POST to the list of methods that can be processed

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

See [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.route) for more information

As per the second question, it's ok as long as your login form makes POST request to the same route (`'/'` in your case).

Comment: Oops. Just cant believe i forgot to add that. Thanks man. Also is there any way i can achieve my second question without repeating the login for each and every route ?